# Trouble with imports and setting python version

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, command-line, anaconda

I'm having trouble getting the same version of Python running from different start points and this is causing problems with imports into my Python script.

I have a python3 script that I'm trying to run from a php app.

```
import sys
import time
import os
import numpy
import pandas
from sklearn import metrics
```

When I run this code from the terminal in VS Code, I get the expected results. From VS Code I get this from os.sys.version

`3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) [GCC 7.3.0]`

When I run this from my PHP app using shell_exec('Python path/to/script.py') or Symfony Process

I get this from os.sys.version

`2.7.15+ (default, Oct 7 2019, 17:39:04) [GCC 7.4.0]`

When I run this from my PHP app using shell_exec('Python3 path/to/script.py') or Symfony Process

I get this from os.sys.version

`3.6.8 (default, Oct 7 2019, 12:59:55) [GCC 8.3.0]`

In both cases when running the PHP scripts I get

`import pandas ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

The script also can't load any of the SkLearn modules

But as I said from the VS code terminal or the regular ubuntu terminal the python script runs as expected. From the CLI `which python` gives me `/home/anaconda3/bin/python`

I clearly have a python installation snafu between Anaconda and the regular python install that I don't know how to correct. Too many installations I guess.

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Do you have some PHP code? In general: If you have multiple installations, the one found in the PATH first is used. If you know which python you want to run, why don't you use the full path to the executable?

Comment: The php that triggers the call to the python script is "$process = new Process('python /path/to/start.py');" or "$process = new Process('python3 /path/to/start.py');"

Comment: " If you know which python you want to run, why don't you use the full path to the executable?" because I didn't think of that. :-P Thanks this did it.

Comment: try adding the full path before python. eg: $process = new Process('/my/path/to/the/right/install/python3 /path/to/start.py');

Comment: Cool, we crossposted. You solved it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Erwin got me the answer.

> If you know which python you want to run, why don't you use the full path to the executable?

Duh, too early on a Monday. Thanks!